# Image Not Found Within MvcHtmlString.Create()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a grid column like this:

```
gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "",
  format: (spec) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(
  "<a href='' onclick='RemoveEquipment({0}); return false;'><img src='~/Images/Delete.png' alt='x' /></a>",
  spec.Equipment.EquipmentId))),
```

It works correctly except that the image isn't found.

[image]

Indeed, the chrome console reports: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).`

However, if I place that exact code somewhere else in the web page, on its own, the image will display:

```
<img src='~/Images/Delete.png' alt='x' />
```

Any idea why it won't display within the MvcHtmlString.Create() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde sign wouldn't run in client side html tags. So either put the exact absolute URL or just remove the `~/` from src.

Hope this will help.

Comment: @BobHorn, yes it worked because now image folder is exist in two level up directory.